# How can I get mini/max values _within_ ntile(10) in (hive) sql?

Tags: sql, hive

I have a table such as this:

```
|colA | colB | ... |
| 2  | 12    | ... |
| 9  | 12    | ... |
| 10 | 13    | ... |
| 93 | 12    | ... |
| .. | ..    | ... |
```

I want to discretize the columns using `ntile` and include their 'labels':

```
|colA     | colB    | ... |
| 0 - 7   | 2 - 24  | ... |
| 7 - 12  | 2 - 24 | ... |
| 7 - 12  | 2 - 24 | ... |
| 82 - 95 | 2 - 24 | ... |
```

In my query, I'm using `select ... ntile(10) over (order by colA) ...`. This divides up column `colA` into 10 buckets and returns those buckets.

I want to know the min and max values within those buckets.

This query gives me what I want:

```sql
with raw as (
  select colA, ntile(10) over (order by colA) ntile
  from mytable
)
select ntile, concat(min(colA), '-', max(colA)) label
from raw
group by ntile
```

However, I'd like to avoid using CTE and the added complexity. I'd like to do something like this:

```sql
select ntile(10) over (order by colA) ntile, concat(min(colA), '-', max(colA)) label
form mytable
group by ntile(10) over (order by colA)
```

This obviously doesn't work because I can't use window functions in a group by clause.

Although I'm just showing colA here, in reality, my table has a couple of hundred columns, which will absolutely blow up the first query (in terms of the number of lines).

Any ideas on how I can do a `group by` on an `ntile(..)` function?

For context, I'm basically a poor man's version of feature discretization.
(outside the scope of this question, I know I should be using fancier algorithms for variable clustering/discretization/bucketizaion, but spark is proving to be a bigger pain and the data is too large for our pandas/sklearn environment)

Comment: You can't put a window function inside of a window function. You can not group or "having" on a window function. The query must materialize first, which includes the grouping clause, prior to the window function being evaluated. You will have to query twice, a cte for example.

Comment: A CTE is not really "complex".